# Sendbird send image file

Tags: javascript, sendbird

I'm going through the [JavaScript documentation for Sendbird](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript#open_channel_3_sending_messages) and although the method to send files is there, there is no explanation on what each argument has to be or the different options.

```
channel.sendFileMessage(FILE, FILE_NAME, FILE_TYPE, FILE_SIZE, CUSTOM_DATA, function(message, error){
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }
    console.log(message);
});
```

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214136/create-file-from-drawable-to-send-with-sendbird/40422419#40422419) that guided me a bit, but I'm still unable to send a file.

Has someone been able to send an image with sendbird using JavaScript? I'm looking for a working JS example and/or documentation about the multiple options available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send file message, you only need one of the argument in the function, the one which defines your source. The other arguments is not neccasary for the basic function.

```
channel.sendFileMessage(File, function(message, error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
```

And for the source File, you need to just define the path to it either locally or globally. Hope it was helpful.

Here is a useful link: https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript/blob/master/react-native-sample/SendBirdReactNativeSample/src/pages/chat.js

Answer (score 2):

In React Native, you should pass something like

```
{ uri: 'file://p/q/a.jpg' name: 'a.jpg' type: 'image/jpg' }
```

to sendFileMessage method.

Here's a sample code you should take a look at.

https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript/blob/master/react-native-sample/SendBirdReactNativeSample/src/pages/chat.js#L178

Comment: This solution is no longer working. See https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-JavaScript/issues/19